# numeric value out of range

Tags: java, ms-access

when i am saving the data its giving the error i.e NUMERIC VALUE OUT OF RANGE
I HAVE TAKEN THIS 3 FIELD AS DATATYPE NUMBER IN MS ACCESS DB

i was taken the mobile no as 4343242434 and i have written code for this is:

```
double mno= Long.parseLong(tfmno.getText());
len = tfmno.getText().length();
if(len!=10) {
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Enter The 10 Digit Mobile No","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
return;
}
```

and i was taken the pin code as:2222222 and my code for pincode is:

i

```
nt pincode=Integer.parseInt(tfpcd.getText());
len1 = tfpcd.getText().length();
if(len1!=7) {
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Enter The 7 Digit Pin Code","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
return;
}
```

and i was taken the telephone no as:2222333 and my code for this is:

```
int tele=Integer.parseInt(tftele.getText());
        len2 = tftele.getText().length();
        if(len2!=7){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Enter The 7 Digit Telephone No","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        return;
        }
```

tell me which value is exeeding and what should i do instead

Comment: Why are you parsing as a long and putting it in a double? Longs are 64-bit and so are doubles, but doubles cannot hold large values because of the amount of memory needed to deal with decimals.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't tell us what tftele was, but from the methods invoked, I'm going to guess it's a JTextField.

If so, your problem is that in the first example you are taking your `long` value and assigning to a `double`.

A `double` is a double-precision floating-point value, and as such uses a lot of it's 64-bits of allocated memory for storing values after the decimal place. There is no point in storing your value in a double, espessially after it has been parsed as a long (any decimal place would throw an exception anyways).

I believe that your code should use a `long` value since you parsed it as a long.

Also, think about catching a NumberFormatException when you do the X.parseX(text); statements too; just in case your users type non-numeric values for the text field.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the application should tell you which field/line the error is in.

However, like Jack told you already, it's probably this line: `double mno= Long.parseLong(tfmno.getText());`

Btw, why don't you store the values as text?